Difficulty Understanding the Strong Markov Property
I am having a lot of trouble trying to understand the Strong Markov Property.
To best understand this problem, I am trying to create an example which shows what would happen in a hypothetical situation where the Strong Markov Property were to hold and what would happen if the Strong Markov Property were not to hold. (Ideally a computer simulation/visualization would be ideal for this).
Theoretical Example: For example, consider a discrete time Stochastic Process $X_t$ such that the first entry of the process into state $i$ is considered a Stopping Time $t$ (random variable).
Based on different lecture notes I read on the internet, I tried to summarize the definitions (was quite difficult due to the different notations):

If the Strong Markov Property were to hold: We can see that the probability for the evolution of the process to behave a certain way prior to stopping time and the probability for the evolution of the process to behave a certain way after the Stopping Time ... is not influenced by the Stopping Time.

$$
P\left(\{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}\} \cap \{x_{t+1}, \ldots, x_{t+n}\} | x_t = i\right) = P\left(\{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}\} | x_t = i\right) \cdot P\left(\{x_{t+1}, \ldots, x_{t+n}\} | x_t = i\right)
$$
Using the laws of probability, I tried to expand on these equations:
$$
P\left(\{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}\} | x_t = i\right) = \pi_{x_0} \cdot P_{x_0,x_1} \cdot P_{x_1,x_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot P_{x_{t-2},x_{t-1}}
$$
$$
P\left(\{x_{t+1}, \ldots, x_{t+n}\} | x_t = i\right) = P_{i,x_{t+1}} \cdot P_{x_{t+1},x_{t+2}} \cdot \ldots \cdot P_{x_{t+n-1},x_{t+n}}
$$
$$
P\left(\{x_{0}, \ldots, x_{n-1}\} | x_0 = i\right) = P\left(\{x_{t+1}, \ldots, x_{t+n}\} | x_t = i\right)
$$

If the Strong Markov Property were not to hold: We can see that the probability for the evolution of the process after the Stopping Time is in fact influenced by the Stopping Time itself

$$
P\left(\{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}\} \cap \{x_{t+1}, \ldots, x_{t+n}\} | x_t = i\right) = P\left(\{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}\} | x_t = i\right) \cdot P\left(\{x_{t+1}, \ldots, x_{t+n}\} | \{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}\} \cap \{x_t = i\}\right)
$$
Using the laws of probability, I tried to expand on these equations:
$$
P\left(\{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}\} \cap \{x_{t+1}, \ldots, x_{t+n}\} | x_t = i\right)
$$
$$
P\left(\{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}\} | x_t = i\right) = \pi_{x_0} \cdot P_{x_0,x_1} \cdot P_{x_1,x_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot P_{x_{t-2},x_{t-1}}
$$
$$
P\left(\{x_{t+1}, \ldots, x_{t+n}\} | \{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}\} \cap \{x_t = i\}\right) = \frac{P\left(\{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}, x_t = i, x_{t+1}, \ldots, x_{t+n}\}\right)}{P\left(\{x_0, \ldots, x_{t-1}\} \cap \{x_t = i\}\right)}
$$
While this makes some sense to me, I tried to make an even simpler problem.
Practical Example: Suppose we have some discrete time Stochastic Process $X_t$ which represents the states of a biased coin. The Transition Matrix as P can be defined as:
$$
P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
P_{hh} & P_{ht} \\
P_{th} & P_{tt}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Here, $P_{hh}$, $P_{ht}$, $P_{th}$, and $P_{tt}$ represent the probabilities of transitioning from heads to heads, heads to tails, tails to heads, and tails to tails.
The state of the coin at time $t$ as $X_t$. The stopping time is the event of getting heads at time $t$, which we can denote as $T = \min\{t \geq 0 : X_t = h\}$.

The probability $p1$ of being in state $h$ at time $t+T$ given that we are in state $h$ at time $t=0$ can be represented as:

$$
p_1 = P(X_{t+T} = h | X_0 = h)
$$

The probability $p2$ of being in state $h$ at time $t+T$ given that we are in state $h$ at time $t$ can be represented as:

$$
p_2 = P(X_{t+T} = h | X_t = h)
$$
If the Strong Markov Property is true, then $p_1 = p_2$ . Otherwise $p_1 \neq p_2$.
Conclusion: After much thinking, I think I finally understood this. We say that in a Stochastic Process, the current state only depends on the previous state. However, the previous state depends on the state before it. This goes on recursively. As a result, the current state of the Stochastic Process indirectly depends on the initial state.
However, if the Strong Markov Property is true, then the value of the current state only depends on the state at the previous Stopping Time. This means that the Stochastic Process can be interrupted, and we can make inferences on the probability of the process being in any state at any time .... and not need to look back to the initial conditions, but rather only up to the stopping time.
I am not sure why the Strong Markov Property is useful and if my understanding is correct. Can someone help me out?

In this case, I think the probabilistic interpretation is more insightful than the formal proof.
The way I was taught to think about this in my markov chains and martingales course, was that you should imagine the process as being governed by a "law".
The Markov property says that the law of the process, conditioned on the past equals the law of the process conditioned on the present.
Now the strong Markov property is a generalization to stopping times. If we have a stopping time $\tau$, then the law of the process $X_{\tau + t}$ conditioned on all the information up to $\tau$ for $t \geq 0$ equals the law of the process started at $X_\tau$.
You can imagine the markov process as a frog jumping on Lilly pads. Where the frog jumps will only depend on which pad it currently is on.
Now imagine we have three lilly pads $A,B,C$. Consider the stopping time $\tau_A^5$ marking when we jump on $A$ for the 5th time. The strong markov property says that the law of the process after jumping on $A$ for the 5th time is the same as the process started from $A$.


@ Sam Kirkiles: thank you for this wonderful answer about frogs! can you please look at the example I made using the coins? does it look logical to you?

@konofoso Yes, let $\tau_H^k$ be flipping your $k\text{th}$ heads. Then strong Markov says $P(X_{\tau_{H}^k + n} = H| \mathcal{F}{{\tau{H}^k}}) =P_H(X_n =H)$

In other words, the probability of flipping heads $n$ steps after your $kth$ heads equals the probability of staring at heads and flipping heads on your $nth$ flip

If you see a square, it is a stackexchange glitch, and I tried to write the $\sigma$-algebra/ information up to the kth heads.

thank you so much for everything, where is "figure 1.1" from? I would like to read the original source :)

BTW - do you have any opinions about this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4914040/how-to-prove-that-a-stochastic-process-follows-the-strong-markov-property

@konofoso Markov chains and mixing times by Peres!

thanks! by the ways ... I turned your comment into a new question! :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4914896/is-it-possible-to-observe-the-strong-markov-property-in-real-life
