How to prove that a Stochastic Process follows the Strong Markov Property?
I am trying to understand how to prove that a given Stochastic Process follows the Strong Markov Property
A quick recap: A Stochastic Process $X_t$ is said to have the Strong Markov Property if for any stopping time $\tau$ and any time $ t \geq 0 $, the future values $ X_{\tau + t} - X_{\tau} $, given the past and present values up to time $ \tau $, depend only on the present value $ X_{\tau} $ and are independent of the past values:
$$ P(X_{\tau + t} \in A | X_s, s \leq \tau) = P(X_{\tau + t} \in A | X_{\tau}) $$
for every $ t \geq 0 $, every stopping time $ \tau $, and every Borel set $ A $ (I think the Borel set is a fancy way of saying all possible combinations of outcomes that can be assumed by the process, i.e. the sigma algebra).
I was not able to find a clear definition on what conditions need to be satisfied for a Stochastic Process to follow the Strong Markov Property.
However, I read some previous questions (e.g. Show the Markov Property of a Poisson Process) in which previous users had asked how to prove if a Poisson Process follows the Strong Markov Property. Here is what I understood:
For a Stochastic Process to follow the Strong Markov Property, the following two conditions need to be satisfied:

Stationary Increments: A stochastic process $\{X(t), t \geq 0\}$ has stationary increments if for all $n \geq 1$, for all $0 \leq t_1 < t_2 < ... < t_n$, and for all $h > 0$, the joint distribution of $\{X(t_2) - X(t_1), ..., X(t_n) - X(t_{n-1})\}$ is the same as the joint distribution of $\{X(t_2 + h) - X(t_1 + h), ..., X(t_n + h) - X(t_{n-1} + h)\}$.

As I understand, this means that the distribution of the increments is the same for equal length time intervals, regardless of the starting time.

Independent Increments: A stochastic process $\{X(t), t \geq 0\}$ has independent increments if for all $n \geq 1$, for all $0 \leq t_1 < t_2 < ... < t_n$, the random variables $X(t_1), X(t_2) - X(t_1), ..., X(t_n) - X(t_{n-1})$ are independent.

I tried to quantify these two conditions in easier terms for me to understand:
1) Stationary Increments:

For a stochastic process $\{X(t), t \geq 0\}$, define the increments as $X(t + h) - X(t)$ for any $t \geq 0$ and $h > 0$

Then, show that for any two time points $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that $t_2 > t_1$, and for any $h > 0$, the distribution of the increment over the interval $[t_1, t_1 + h]$ (i.e., the distribution of $X(t_1 + h) - X(t_1)$) is the same as the distribution of the increment over the interval $[t_2, t_2 + h]$ (i.e., the distribution of $X(t_2 + h) - X(t_2)$).


2) Independent Increments:

For a stochastic process $\{X(t), t \geq 0\}$, define the increments as $X(t + h) - X(t)$ for any $t \geq 0$ and $h > 0$.

Consider any two disjoint time intervals $[t_1, t_1 + h]$ and $[t_2, t_2 + k]$ such that $t_1 + h \leq t_2$ (i.e. thi ensures the intervals are disjoint).

Show that the increments over these disjoint intervals are independent: For any sequence of events $A$ and $B$ in outcomes generated by $\{X(u): t_1 \leq u \leq t_1 + h\}$ and $\{X(v): t_2 \leq v \leq t_2 + k\}$ we have $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.


Are Stationary Increments and Independent Increments the only necessary conditions required to show that ANY Stochastic Process follows the Strong Markov Property? If so, why are these two conditions (i.e. Stationary Increments and Independent Increments) necessary?

Neither of those conditions is necessary.

Look at $X_t=t^{2}X$, for example.

These conditions are satisfied by levy processes, but there are more general processes as the other commenter suggested

thanks everyone for your replies ... is there any common criteria which can be used to prove that a stochastic process follows the strong markov property?
