Is it possible to observe the Strong Markov Property in real life?
I have been spending a lot of time trying to understand what exactly is the Strong Markov Property and what kinds of stochastic processes obey the Strong Markov Property and what kinds don't.
In simple terms, the Strong Markov Property says : The probability of flipping heads n steps after your kth  heads equals the probability of staring at heads and flipping heads on your nth flip (quoted from the comments: Difficulty Understanding the Strong Markov Property)
I have read that a Discrete Time Markov Chain (DTMC) always follows the Strong Markov Property. So I decided to try and simulate some random data from a DTMC and check for different values of (n,k) if the Strong Markov Property applies.
Here is my logic:

Imagine there is a stochastic coin such that if the current flip is heads, the next flip is heads with p=0.7 and tails  with p=0.3 If the current flip is tails, the next flip is tails with p=0.7 and heads with p=0.3
The coin always starts with heads
We simulate 100 random flips of this coin. Then repeat this 1000 times to create the analysis file
p1 =  probability of flipping heads n steps after your kth  heads
p2 =  probability of staring at heads and flipping heads on your nth flip
From the analysis file, for different values of (n,k) we calculate the absolute value of p1-p2
If the Strong Markov Property holds, then abs(p1-p2) should be close to 0 for different values of (n,k)

Here is an R script which attempts to do this:
num_flips <- 1000
num_reps <- 10000

coin_flips <- matrix(nrow=num_reps, ncol=num_flips)

for (j in 1:num_reps) {
    # Set first flip to be heads
    coin_flips[j, 1] <- "H"
    

    for (i in 2:num_flips) {
        # If the last flip was heads
        if (coin_flips[j, i - 1] == "H") {
            # The next flip is heads with probability 0.7
            coin_flips[j, i] <- ifelse(runif(1) < 0.7, "H", "T")
        } else {
            # If the last flip was tails
            # The next flip is tails with probability 0.7
            coin_flips[j, i] <- ifelse(runif(1) < 0.7, "T", "H")
        }
    }
}


results <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=10)

# Loop over k and n
for (k in 1:10) {
    for (n in 1:10) {
      
        outcomes_P1 <- character(num_reps)
        outcomes_P2 <- character(num_reps)
        
        # Loop
        for (j in 1:num_reps) {
            # Find the kth head
            indices_of_kth_heads <- which(coin_flips[j, ] == "H")[k]
            
           
            outcomes_P1[j] <- coin_flips[j, indices_of_kth_heads + n]
            
            
            outcomes_P2[j] <- coin_flips[j, n]
        }
        
   
        P1 <- sum(outcomes_P1 == "H") / length(outcomes_P1)
        P2 <- sum(outcomes_P2 == "H") / length(outcomes_P2)
        
        # Absolute difference between P1 and P2
        results[k, n] <- abs(P1 - P2)
    }
}

print(results)

As we can see, the difference in absolute values is quite small for some combinations of (n,k), possibly suggesting that the Strong Markov Property is (sometimes) obeyed:
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,] 0.316 0.115 0.038 0.001 0.011 0.009 0.007 0.014 0.006 0.002
 [2,] 0.306 0.091 0.010 0.009 0.006 0.006 0.027 0.004 0.004 0.008
 [3,] 0.285 0.100 0.018 0.006 0.004 0.025 0.004 0.002 0.031 0.049
 [4,] 0.296 0.086 0.022 0.006 0.007 0.005 0.005 0.010 0.054 0.063
 [5,] 0.291 0.105 0.041 0.004 0.016 0.028 0.008 0.038 0.072 0.056
 [6,] 0.297 0.085 0.010 0.026 0.017 0.012 0.030 0.023 0.050 0.044
 [7,] 0.274 0.069 0.007 0.008 0.032 0.038 0.019 0.049 0.056 0.060
 [8,] 0.282 0.066 0.021 0.030 0.050 0.019 0.029 0.031 0.061 0.043
 [9,] 0.284 0.103 0.062 0.040 0.025 0.027 0.027 0.031 0.049 0.054
[10,] 0.309 0.126 0.055 0.007 0.036 0.008 0.027 0.024 0.050 0.050

I just wanted to ask:

From a mathematical perspective, can such a simulation be used to indirectly show that a given stochastic process follows the Strong Markov Property?
How can I design a stochastic process that would not follow the Strong Markov Property and empirically observe this from a simulation?


To cook up a process which does not satisfy strong markov, you'd have to make some process with some dependence on the past

How about a process which acts like fair coin flips but after it hits its 5th heads, it stays in that state forever. The law after the 5th heads is just that with probability 1 it always flips heads. But the law starting from heads is to act like a fair coin for a bit. So strong markov doesn't hold for this process.

I'm not sure how easy it will be to convince yourself of these things by simulation. As Feller writes in volume 1, probability is like geometry or chess. You have a bit of an intuitive feeling for it that many times comes before the strictly logical content. Maybe with strong markov, just think back to the frog on the lily pads for intuition.

If this program works as verbally described by the definition of $p_1$ and  $p_2$ should the 0.316 in the top left corner not be zero (assuming that is $n=k=1$), or am I missing something?

The use of ifelse is incorrect in a for loop in the R language. Should use if and else.

@ Sam Kirkiles: about the coin after the 5th heads that stays there forever. I have read this example before and it seems trivial to me. if it stays there forever ... the process is done forever! no markov property applies! :)
